# When is self statement true and when is false?

Tags: python, if-statement, self

Can someone explain this if self.cards condition? When will it be True and when will it be False?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.cards = []

def __str__(self):
    if self.cards:
        rep = ""
        for card in self.cards:
            rep += str(card) + " "
    else:
        rep = "<empty>"
    return rep
```

Comment: Check this out https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: `self.cards` is probably a member list of the enclosing class. The condition `if self.cards` checks if said list has at least one element, in which case it iterates over each card and adds its string representation to the final result.

Comment: it is list. thank you, I understand it now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object can be tested for truth value in Python. The following values are considered false:

None

False

zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.

any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.

any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.

instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value `False`.

All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

In this case cards is `False` when it is empty because it is a list. When the object is created, `__init__()` creates the cards empty list, so that if statement's condition is always `False` when the object is created.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should probably show us when self.cards is used for the first time.
Assuming it is some sort of a container(`list`, `set` or `dict`) it will be true if there are elements in it and false if it is empty.

Comment: it is list, first used in __init__