# What does "if self:" mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, if-statement, self

Example:

```
class Bird:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = "chirp!"

    def reproduce_sound(self):
        if self:
            print(self.sound)

bird = Bird()
bird.reproduce_sound()
```

What does `if self:` mean? What is the case where the `reproduce_sound` function call prints nothing?

Comment: In this specific case, I think it will always print.  But in general, a class could override the `__bool__` method such that `if self` would be false under desired conditions.

Comment: What is self https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/ can self be false? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103320/when-is-self-statement-true-and-when-is-false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It checks the truth value of the instance and only prints if it is `True`. In your example the check doesn't do anything useful and will always print something. You can override the `__bool__` method to change its default behaviour.

For example:

```
class Bird:
    ...
    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(self.sound)
```

Then:

```
b = Bird()
b.reproduce_sound()   # Prints "chirp!"
b.sound = 0           # or any falsy value, such as None or ""
b.reproduce_sound()   # Won't print anything because b == False
```